# Open hazelcast console for a specific port

Tags: hazelcast

Is there a way to get the key-value pairs in a map present in a hazelcast cluster? I dont have access to hazelcast mancenter. From what I read the console app cannot be configured to connect to a specific hazelcast port. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, management center needs license version if you have more number of nodes. So better to write your own Java utility tool.

1. Create a Hazelcast client instance
2. Get hold of the Distributed map
3. Iterate over the map to get the required Key-Value pairs or create Predicates to get the Entries based on wildcard search.